# Where to learn about continued fractions?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, continued-fractions

I sought a convergent subsequence of $\sin n$, and I met a proof that utilizes continued fractions. I always stumble upon things related to them as well. So, I would like to learn about them. What is a good resource where I can learn about them (in a rigorous manner)? Thanks.

Comment: sometime ago I've used this: http://www.math.binghamton.edu/dikran/478/Ch7.pdf

Comment: Two elementary introductions that are readable and mathematically sound are [**Continued Fractions**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0064IRSO8) by C. D. Olds and [**Continued Fractions**](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0486696308) by A. Ya. Khinchin.

Answer (score 0):

Chrystal's Algebra Volume Two.  See this note for a link to an online electronic copy: http://recursed.blogspot.com/2009/12/chrystals-algebra-is-available.html

For something more recent, try Doug Hensley's Continued Fractions.